# SVG expand line verticaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

The question is how to expand line vertical without stroke-dasharray. Don't know how to do it right. This is my example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_3" x="0px" y="0px" width="286px" height="286px" viewBox="0 0 286 286" enable-background="new 0 0 286 286" xml:space="preserve">
        <line fill="none" stroke="#3AB0F3" id="stroke-dasharray" stroke-width="244" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="143" y1="0" x2="143" y2="286"/><animate
                attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
                from="0, 0" to="143, 143"
                dur="3s"
                repeatCount="1"/></line>
    </svg>
```

Main problem on this is how to set property on SVG to expand it vertical without stroke-dasharray.

And some jQuery code from d3 charts.

```
var mySVG1 = $('#Layer_3').drawsvg({
                duration: 3000
            });

mySVG1.drawsvg('animate');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in d3 :

```
d3.select('#lineSelect').transition().duration(1000).attr('y2',700)
```

This would change your height from 286 to 700. But to see this here I have changed the original height to 2 as the output window is small.

But to actually see this you need its container, i.e the svg to adjust height to. For the time being, I only changed it to window.innerHeight but it can be updated the same as the line.

```js
var height = window.innerHeight;

d3.select('svg').attr('height', height)

d3.select('#lineSelect').transition().delay(500).duration(1000).attr('y2',700) //transition height after half a second
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="286px" height="286px" viewBox="0 0 286 286" enable-background="new 0 0 286 286" xml:space="preserve">
  <line id='lineSelect' fill="none" stroke="#3AB0F3" stroke-width="244" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="143" y1="0" x2="143" y2="2" />
</svg>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/27u7g3dt/2/

Comment: make note, I added an id of 'lineSelect' to the line. If you can't add this then just select the line anyway you can, for example d3.select('line'), baring in mind if theres more than one line this wont work, you would have to select the index of what line you want